# problem with navigation based template

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nib

hii every one

i am creating a navigation based application & i am designing screens programatically , i need to have 2 bar buttons ie left barbutton item & right bar button item  so i have used following code in  - (void)loadView  method but its crashing when controller enters loadview method,,can any one tell me whats wrong in this code, thanx in advance

```
  self.title = @"Add Item";
 self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] 
 initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemCancel 
 target:self action:@selector(cancel_Clicked:)] autorelease];

 self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] 
 initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemSave 
 target:self action:@selector(save_Clicked:)] autorelease];
 self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor groupTableViewBackgroundColor];
```

Comment: what is the crash log you are getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code

```
UIBarButtonItem *flipButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] 
                           initWithTitle:@"Flip"                                            
                           style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered 
                           target:self 
                           action:@selector(flipView)];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = flipButton;
[flipButton release];
```

Comment: it worked fine thnak u , i have used following code to change background color but its crashing what can be done to fix this      self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor groupTableViewBackgroundColor];

Comment: self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];

Comment: no again its craching,,this is the crash log-- warning: Unable to restore previously selected frame.

Comment: Call the same line inside viewDdLoad method

Answer (score 0):

Try following code,

```
UIButton *btn=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[btn addTarget:self action:@selector(yourfunctionToCall:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
btn.frame=CGRectMake(3, 2, 53, 30);
UIBarButtonItem *btnBack=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:btn];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem=btnBack;
[btnBack release];
[btn release];
```

same way create for rightBarButtonItem

Answer (score 0):

```
 self.title = @"Add Item";
   UIBarButtonItem *cancelbutton   = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] 
     initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemCancel 
     target:self action:@selector(cancel_Clicked:)] autorelease];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem=cancelbutton;
[cancelbutton release];

     UIBarButtonItem *savebutton = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] 
     initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemSave 
     target:self action:@selector(save_Clicked:)] autorelease];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem=savebutton;
[savebutton release];
```